# react-scripts error handle with componentDidCatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-scripts

**First main question** (Solved)

I try [example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0110) from [off doc React Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) on my dev server with **react-scripts** (**npm start**) and after the first trigger **componentDidCatch** an error appears in the browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

and the page does not respond to my actions. This example work fine in sandbox codepen.io and with serve -s build. How to solve this problem?

**Second question**

What is the best way to remove a message from the browser console?

```
Uncaught Error: I crashed!
```

I don't want error messages to be visible in the browser console

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
```

App.js

```
import React from "react"

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            errorInfo: null
        };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
        // Catch errors in any components below and re-render with error message
        this.setState({error: error, errorInfo: errorInfo})
        // You can also log error messages to an error reporting service here
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.errorInfo) {
            // Error path
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Something went wrong.</h2>
                    <details
                        style={{
                        whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'
                    }}>
                        {this.state.error && this
                            .state
                            .error
                            .toString()}
                        <br/> {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
                    </details>
                </div>
            );
        }
        // Normally, just render children
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

class BuggyCounter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        };
        this.handleClick = this
            .handleClick
            .bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(({counter}) => ({
            counter: counter + 1
        }));
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.counter === 5) {
            // Simulate a JS error
            throw new Error('I crashed!');
        }
        return <h1 onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.counter}</h1>;
    }
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>
                    This is an example of error boundaries in React 16.
                    <br/><br/>
                    Click on the numbers to increase the counters.
                    <br/>
                    The counter is programmed to throw when it reaches 5. This simulates a
                    JavaScript error in a component.
                </b>
            </p>
            <hr/>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <p>These two counters are inside the same error boundary. If one crashes, the
                    error boundary will replace both of them.</p>
                <BuggyCounter/>
                <BuggyCounter/>
            </ErrorBoundary>
            <hr/>
            <p>These two counters are each inside of their own error boundary. So if one
                crashes, the other is not affected.</p>
            <ErrorBoundary><BuggyCounter/></ErrorBoundary>
            <ErrorBoundary><BuggyCounter/></ErrorBoundary>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have answer on my **first question**. Sorry I forgot that I downloaded files from the sandbox and install this.  I reinstalled react using **npx create-react-app** and the error **process is not defined** no longer appeared. Sorry

Comment: I suggest to remove your first question then, as long as there are no answers referring to it. I recommend not to ask multiple questions at once anyway, because that way nobody can answer who knows the answer to only one of the questions. So you will get no answers at all.